# How to connect arduino and android app with gsm internet?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arduino, gsm

I am making a prototype for my final paper (Electronic technician) and the purpose is: A real-time car tracker using GPS and arduino UNO to this, and an android app (made in android studio with Kotlin) to connect the arduino and receive some data to help the user in case of accidents, robbery and theft. The main problem is, how can I connect the arduino GPS and the android app in long distances? With internet? For this, we thought about using the GSM800L module to this function, but we don't have any Idea to implement this two ideas together, we know Kotlin has some functions to GSM, however, we don't know how to use it in the code. If someone has the answer to this questions, I would really aprecciate it.

Comment: over a server in cloud

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a mediation device.

- Arduino GSM in the car
- Android app
- Server of some sort, with a database and connectivity to the internet

Arduino sends data over HTTP or even better using MQTT.

Android app read data from server or even better get notifications and update the screen.